# SSH Key Apparently Expired:

Tags: ssh-keys

I was under the impression that SSH keys did not have an expiry, so I am a bit puzzled as to why a client came to me yesterday to advise that 2 of our keys had:

Message from client:

```
I can see that the key on each account is due for a refresh today.
xxxx1282xxxx Key Expiry Date: 11 April 2019 17:10
xxxx2214xxxx Key Expiry Date: 11 April 2019 17:02
```

Any idea how they got to this, as this may now involve a piece of work where I have to grab expiry dates for over 100 keys....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traditional SSH keys have no expiry; in fact they have no metadata whatsoever (except maybe a comment field). Some companies have central authorized key management and implement their own policies regarding key expiry – the dates in that case are stored in some company-specific or system-specific format, not within the key itself.

It's likely that your client has simply decided that all keypairs must be rotated every X years or so (similar to what's done for TLS certificates).

Various "certificate" formats (X.509, PGP, OpenSSH certs) *may* have expiry dates. For example, if your public key starts with "ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com" instead of the usual "ssh-rsa", then it is a certificate with metadata – expiry date possibly included. (Use `ssh-keygen -L` to view the certificate's contents.) Other certificate formats are even more unlikely to be used with SSH.